# How to use buttons with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

How would I use [twitter bootstraps radio buttons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons), if you cant frigged submit the button to POST.

If I do  like they show there, it submits the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to write additional functionality if you want to handle form submission.  I believe the plugin only provides UI functionality.

Comment: See below answer. I had to use both methods from the answers to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `type="button"` to your button and it won't submit the form.

Comment: +1 But this didn't help my situation. I still couldn't submit to post. I had to write jquery to update a hidden form field's value for each buttons value in order to submit the data to $_POST.

But doing this allowed me to do the above.